# Remove extra space in drawer header

Tags: flutter, dart

I want achieve this drawer header
[image]

But mine have lot of space.How to remove the extra space in drawer header?

[image]

**Code**

```
class AppDrawer extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          _createHeader(),
          _createDrawerItem(
            icon: Icons.contacts,
            text: 'Contacts',
            onTap: () {},
          ),
          _createDrawerItem(
            icon: Icons.event,
            text: 'Events',
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _createDrawerItem(
      {required IconData icon,
      required String text,
      required GestureTapCallback onTap}) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(icon),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
            child: Text(text),
          )
        ],
      ),
      onTap: onTap,
    );
  }

  Widget _createHeader() {
    return const DrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text("Name"),
          subtitle: Text("Email"),
          dense: true,
          leading: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.people)),
        ));
  }
}
```

---

Ignore this line epfokeofkpekf efewfefeefefefefefefewf fewfef fefef
fefjoej jifjeojfo oijoewfjoej oijfoijfoiejf rvw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `DrawerHeader()` you can use `Container()`.

> Example:

```dart
class AppDrawer extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          _createHeader(),
          _createDrawerItem(
            icon: Icons.contacts,
            text: 'Contacts',
            onTap: () {},
          ),
          _createDrawerItem(
            icon: Icons.event,
            text: 'Events',
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _createDrawerItem(
      {required IconData icon,
      required String text,
      required GestureTapCallback onTap}) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(icon),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
            child: Text(text),
          )
        ],
      ),
      onTap: onTap,
    );
  }

  Widget _createHeader() {
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text("Name"),
          subtitle: Text("Email"),
          dense: true,
          leading: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.people)),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of DrawerHeader you can use Container or SizedBox to change its height according to the requirement.

Comment: Maybe share some code for that answer?